# Get hints of reserved words in a working IDLE console?

Tags: python

Help() function helps a lot to save brain's memories during coding.

```
>>> help(list)
Help on class list in module builtins:
class list(object)
 |  list() -> new empty list
 |  list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
>>> dir(zip)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

I can retrieve information about sequence, functions and classes.

However

```
 >>> help(assert)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    help(assert)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can I get hints of reserve words like 'assert' within IDIE window ?

Comment: If you want a list of keywords, then you can check `keyword.kwlist` (`import keyword`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **[keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)**, you need to put them in quotes (otherwise `help(keyword)` would not be a syntactically correct statement).

```
>>> help('assert')

The "assert" statement
**********************

Assert statements are a convenient way to insert debugging assertions
into a program:
...
```

You can use the [`keyword` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html) to discover what exactly the Python grammar's keywords are.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap statements/keywords in quotes to get info about them:

```
>>> help('assert')
```